# Weak converge of probabilty measure on Polish spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a Polish space. It is known that the space of probability measures on $X$ is a Polish space with respect to the weak topology. Suppose that for a family of probability measures $(\mu_k)$ on $X$ for any bounded continuous function $g$ we have $|\int_X g(d\mu_k-d\mu_l)|\rightarrow 0$ as $k,l \rightarrow \infty.$ Can we say that $\mu_k$ converges in weak topology to some probability measure $\mu$?

In topological vector spaces probably this is enough to give the weak converge as we will have a Cauchy net, and from completeness there must be a limit. However a general metric space doesn't have to be a vector space so "Cauchy" sequence does not make sense unless we are explicitly working with the metric (and in case of weak convergence the metrics that give the topology is rather hard to work with). In case when $X$ is Hausdorff, finite Radon measures on $X$ is a TVS and probability measures is a closed convex set in such space so the result follows as the seminorms of the above gives the topology. But in this case I have to assume I have a Hausdorff Polish space, which is a slightly weak result.

Comment: If $X$ is a Polish space then the space of probability measures on $X$, $\mathcal{P}(X)$, is also a Polish space with respect to the Levy-Prokhorov distance which metrizes the topology of weak convergence of probability measure. By completeness given your hypothesis we can conclude that a limit measure $\mu$ indeed exists. This is all proved in books like Billingsley's _Convergence of Probability Measures_.

Comment: Your condition implies $(\mu_k)$ is Cauchy for the Wasserstein distance $W_1$. Now I don't remember: does $W_1$ metrize the weak convergence and is complete when $X$ is Polish?

Comment: @Shiva How $|\int_X g(d\mu_k-d\mu_l)|$ is related to the Lévy-Prokhorov distance ?